# Como transformar todo o Dataset em valores monetarios, ou pelo menos arredonda-los

Tags: python, python-requests

**Essa é uma parte de uma coluna do dataset:**

```
0     1.347688e+05

1     1.563599e+05

2     1.788441e+05

3     1.983543e+05
```

**Tentei isso:**

```
from babel.numbers import format_decimal

format_decimal(df.Receita_liquida, locale='en_US')
```

**mas recebi isso>>>** `[<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]`

**Se eu fizer:**

```
format_decimal(1.347688e+05, locale='en_US')
```

**retorna>>>** `134,768.8`

**que seria suficiente, então preciso otimizar.

Comment: Boa tarde, João com o que vc está lendo esse dataframe?

Comment: Boa noite
estou lendo com pandas, o arquivo está em formato xlsx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **mas recebi isso>>>** `[<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]`

Você está passando a coluna inteira do DataFrame como parâmetro para a função `format_decimal`, que espera um número.

Use o método `apply()` do DataFrame passando a função que deve ser aplicada a cada elemento da coluna e atribua o resultado de volta à coluna `Receita_liquida`.

```
df['Receita_liquida'] = df['Receita_liquida'].apply(format_decimal, locale = 'en_US')
```

Ou, usando uma função lambda (desnecessário, mas fica mais fácil de entender):

```
df['Receita_liquida'] = df['Receita_liquida'].apply(lambda x: format_decimal(x, locale='en_US'))
```

Isso é o máximo que dá para sugerir com o que você colocou na pergunta.

Comment: Entendi. Deu certo! Muito obrigado pela ajuda Guilherme !!